# Merging two UIImageViews, one of them after been modified with transforms, with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I'm trying to create a view controller to mix two UIImages. One of them will be static, actin as background, the other can be scaled, dragged and rotated to place it where I want inside the first one.

I created a test view Controller like this:

[image]

Both blue background (`_backImageView`) and Mario image (`_marioImageView`) are UIImageViews at the same level (no one is child of the other). I handle all the gesture recognizers like this:

```
@interface ViewController () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinch;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIRotationGestureRecognizer *rotation;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

  _pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
  [_marioImageView addGestureRecognizer:_pan];

  _pinch = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(resize:)];
  [_marioImageView addGestureRecognizer:_pinch];

  _rotation = [[UIRotationGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rotate:)];
  [_marioImageView addGestureRecognizer:_rotation];
}



- (void)move:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
{
  CGPoint translation = [pan translationInView:_backImageView];

  CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake(pan.view.center.x + translation.x,
                              pan.view.center.y + translation.y);

  CGPoint newBottomRight = CGPointMake(newCenter.x + pan.view.frame.size.width / 2,
                                     newCenter.y + pan.view.frame.size.height / 2);

  CGPoint newOrigin = CGPointMake(newCenter.x - pan.view.frame.size.width / 2,
                                newCenter.y - pan.view.frame.size.height / 2);

  if (CGRectContainsPoint(_backImageView.frame, newBottomRight) &&
    CGRectContainsPoint(_backImageView.frame, newOrigin)) {

    pan.view.center = newCenter;
    [pan setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:_backImageView];
  }
}

- (void)resize:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinch
{
  if (CGRectContainsRect(_backImageView.frame, pinch.view.frame)) {
    pinch.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(pinch.view.transform, pinch.scale, pinch.scale);
    pinch.scale = 1.0;
  }
}

- (void)rotate:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)rotation
{
  if (CGRectContainsRect(_backImageView.frame, rotation.view.frame)) {
    rotation.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(rotation.view.transform, rotation.rotation);
    rotation.rotation = 0;
  }
}
```

Then, when i touch the "Mix Images" button, this is what it does (
`_finalImageView` is another UIImageView to see the result image of the mix.

```
- (IBAction)mixImages:(id)sender
{
  UIImage *backImage = _backImageView.image;
  UIImage *marioImage = _marioImageView.image;

  CGSize finalSize = backImage.size;
  CGSize marioSize = marioImage.size;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(finalSize);

  [backImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, finalSize.width, finalSize.height)];

  CGPoint relativeOrigin = [_marioImageView convertPoint:_marioImageView.frame.origin toView:_backImageView];

  [marioImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(relativeOrigin.x,
                                  relativeOrigin.y,
                                  marioSize.width,
                                  marioSize.height)];

  UIImage *finalImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  [_finalImageView setImage:finalImage];
}
```

The problem is that, in the final image, **the Mario image is showed without any transformation** (no scale, no rotation, anything).

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when you do `imageView.image`, it just returns the `image` without any transformation. You need to save all those transformations, and you need to write your own code, to extract the transformed image from the image view.

One way is to screenshot the imageview after the rotation/scale/transform:

```
    //call this method after the rotation/scaling is done i.e in your mix method
    -(UIImage *)screenshotImageView :(UIImageView *)imgV{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imgV.frame.size);

    CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(c, imgV.frame.origin.x, imgV.frame.origin.y);

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:c];
       image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;

    }
```

So in this case, your two images to merge method would be:

```
    UIImage *backImage = [self screenshotImageView:_backImageView];
    UIImage *marioImage =[self screenshotImageView:_marioImageView];
```

Use the image returned to merge the images as you want to.

Another way is to get the transformed image based on the imageproperties:

Let's say you flipped the image in imageView, and if you want to get the flipped image:

You can try:

```
     UIImage* flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imgView.image.CGImage
                                                scale:imgView.image.scale
                                          orientation:UIImageOrientationUpMirrored];
```